# In captureSuccess move and rename the file

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have 2 smartphones that saves audio file in different folder, one in the root and other in root/Audio folder. What I'm trying to do is, whenever the captureAudio is success, I don't want to save it into default folder(Audio or root). I wanted create a folder called Test(example) and rename the audio file into according to my needs. This is what I got so far, and gives me error about [Object] [Object] has no method moveTo;

```
    function captureAudio() {
// Launch device audio recording application, allowing user to capture up to 2 audio clips
    navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, fail, {limit: 1});
}

function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    var entry = mediaFiles.fullPath;
    var file = code + "_" + n + ".m4a";
    var folder = "Test";

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        function (fileSys) {
                fileSys.root.getDirectory(folder, {create: true, exclusive: false},
                function (directory) {
                    entry.moveTo(directory, file,
                        success, fail);
                }, fail);
        }, fail);
}
```

Comment: wats de extension u getting in entry.name ?? ur code is working at my end.. I have tested with cordova 3.0

Comment: It's giving me Sound%23.m4a.

Comment: Oh i didnt mean that when i try to do in the same folder 'Sounds'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow i made it,

```
var captureSuccess = function (mediaFiles) {
    // SystemURI require string and path2 will deal it and must not use file:/(path)
    var path = mediaFiles[0].fullPath;
    var path2 = path.slice(0, 5) + "//" + path.slice(5);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(path2, successMoveTo, fail);
}

function successMoveTo(entry) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        function (fileSys) {
            fileSys.root.getDirectory(folder, {create: true, exclusive: false},
                function (directory) {
                    entry.moveTo(directory, file,
                        success, fail);
            }, fail);
    }, fail);
}
```