# Renaming file in filesystem after download in Phonegap Android

Tags: android, cordova, file-transfer, file-rename, html5-filesystem

I am having a requirement in Android Phonegap app where I have to show the downloads in progress and All downloads tabs side by side and when the user is downloading some file it ll only be shown in progess tab, while for android its showing on all downloads tab also as android create a file structure before complete download.I had renamed the file before download like abc.mp3.download but after download i have to rename it to abc.mp3 so that it can be usable but i cant able to do it. for renaming i have used the below code

```
fileTransfer.download(elementTitle,filePath, function(entry) {

var dwnnam = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/')+1,filePath.lastIndexOf('.'));
alert("file name -- " + dwnnam);
var destination = "file:///mnt/sdcard/Project/";
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///mnt/sdcard/TechTime/", 
function(destination) {
entry.moveTo(destination, "abc.mp3" ,success,fail);
})
```

Comment: Hi Divesh,this has no connection with onprogress event its aready there in my app

Comment: please provide me solution to rename downloaded file

Comment: what is the error u get in logcat

Comment: Also check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458019/in-capturesuccess-move-and-rename-the-file#comment32385383_21458019) it mgt help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the below code worked for me

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,function (fileSys) {
    fileSys.root.getDirectory("myFolder", {
        create: true, 
        exclusive: false
    },
    function (directory) {
        entry.moveTo(directory, "file.pdf", success, fail);
    }, fail);
}, fail);

function success(fileEntry) {
    console.log("New Path: " + fileEntry.fullPath);
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```